# Strange behavior of keras v1.2.2 vs. keras v2+ (HUGE differences in accuracy)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, theano

Today I've ran into some very strange behavior of Keras. *When I try to do a classification run on the iris-dataset with a simple model, keras version 1.2.2 gives me +- 95% accuracy, whereas a keras version of 2.0+ predicts the same class for every training example (leading to an accuracy of +- 35%, as there are three types of iris)*.  The only thing that makes my model predict +-95% accuracy is downgrading keras to a version below 2.0:

I think it is a problem with Keras, as I have tried the following things, all do not make a difference;

- Switching activation function in the last layer (from Sigmoid to softmax).
- Switching backend (Theano and Tensorflow both give roughly same performance).
- Using a random seed.
- Varying the number of neurons in the hidden layer (I only have 1 hidden layer in this simple model).
- Switching loss-functions.

As the model is very simple and it runs on it's own (You just need the easy-to-obtain iris.csv dataset) I decided to include the entire code;

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

#Load data
data_frame = pd.read_csv("iris.csv", header=None)
data_set = data_frame.values
X = data_set[:, 0:4].astype(float)
Y = data_set[:, 4]

#Encode class values as integers
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)

# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)

def baseline_model():
    #Create & Compile model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=4, init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

#Create Wrapper For Neural Network Model For Use in scikit-learn
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=200, batch_size=5, verbose=0)

#Create kfolds-cross validation
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)

#Evaluate our model (Estimator) on dataset (X and dummy_y) using a 10-fold cross-validation procedure (kfold).
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold)
print("Accuracy: {:2f}% ({:2f}%)".format(results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

if anyone wants to replicate the error here are the dependencies I used to observe the problem:

```
numpy=1.16.4
pandas=0.25.0
sk-learn=0.21.2
theano=1.0.4
tensorflow=1.14.0
```

Comment: The `activation='sigmoid'` in your output layer looks highly suspicious and it certainly shouldn't be there (it should be `softmax` instead); you sure your "good" results with Keras 1.2 come with this same activation? Plus, `init='normal'` should be avoided - you should leave the [default](https://keras.io/layers/core/) (in Keras 2, at least) `glorot_uniform` instead.

Comment: I've tried both; issue persists... I really think its a problem with Keras or some dependency in my environment. Only I don't know where to start looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Keras 2.0, many parameters changed names, there is compatibility layer to keep things working, but somehow it did not apply when using `KerasClassifier`.

In this part of the code:

```
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=200, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
```

You are using the old name `nb_epoch` instead of the modern name of `epochs`. The default value is `epochs=1`, meaning that your model was only being trained for one epoch, producing very low quality predictions.

Also note that here:

```
model.add(Dense(3, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
```

You should be using a `softmax` activation instead of `sigmoid`, as you are using the categorical cross-entropy loss:

```
model.add(Dense(3, init='normal', activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to isolate the issue, if you change `nb_epoch` to `epochs`, (All else being exactly equal) the model predicts very good again, in keras 2 as well. I don't know if this is intended behavior or a bug.

Comment: This is not a bug, the parameter in model.fit was changed from nb_epoch to epochs in Keras 2. Also note the use of a sigmoid activation for multi-class classification is kind of wrong, you should use softmax for this.